# Probability models Suppose $S = \{1,2,3\}$, and $P(\{1\}) = P(\{2\}) + 1/6$, and $P(\{3\}) = 2P(\{2\})$. Computer $P(\{1\}), P(\{2\}), P(\{3\})$

Tags: probability

$S = \{1,2,3\}$, and $P(\{1\}) = P(\{2\}) + 1/6$, and $P(\{3\}) = 2P(\{2\})$. Computer $P(\{1\}), P(\{2\}), P(\{3\})$

$$P(\{2\}) = \frac{P(\{3\})}{2}$$

$$P(\{2\}) = P(\{1\}) - 1/6$$

I don't know how to go about this. I know I can get two equations for $P(\{2\})$ but if I combined them not sure if I could use them to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider that $$ p(\{1\}) + p(\{2\}) + p(\{3\}) = 1 $$ From there, you now have 3 equations and 3 unknowns, which can be solved fairly easily.